# "Maximum recursive updates exceeded." with Vue.js and FullCalendar

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar, vuejs3

I have a Laravel 9 and Vue.js 3 project where I use the [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) package.
All events that come in the calendar are retrieved from the database via Laravel.

**Calendar.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="demo-app">
        <div class="demo-app-main">
            <FullCalendar
                ref="schedule"
                :options='calendarOptions'
            >
                <template v-slot:eventContent="arg">
                    <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b><br/>
                </template>
            </FullCalendar>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom' // solves problem with Vite
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import nlLocal from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/nl';
import bootstrap5Plugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap5';

export default {
    components: {
        FullCalendar
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            calendarOptions: {
                locale: nlLocal,
                plugins: [
                    timeGridPlugin,
                    bootstrap5Plugin
                ],
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
                headerToolbar: null,
                dayHeaderFormat: {
                    weekday: 'short',
                    month: 'long',
                    day: 'numeric',
                    omitCommas: true
                },
                slotLabelFormat: {
                    hour: '2-digit',
                    minute: '2-digit',
                    omitZeroMinute: false,
                    meridiem: 'short'
                },
                titleFormat: {
                    year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'
                },
                nowIndicator: true,
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                events: this.getEvents,
                editable: false,
                selectable: false,
                selectMirror: true,
                dayMaxEvents: true,
                weekends: false,
                eventClick: this.openLessonModal,
                slotDuration: '00:15:00',
                eventColor: '#4782f6'
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getEvents(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            axios.get(this.route('student.schedules.get-lessons'), {
                params: {
                    start: this.$dayjs(info.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    end: this.$dayjs(info.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    class: this.params.class,
                    teacher: this.params.teacher
                }
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    successCallback(response.data);
                })

            // EXAMPLE RESPONSE FROM THE DATABASE:
            // successCallback([
            //     {
            //         "id": 1,
            //         "subject_id": 3,
            //         "teacher_id": 1,
            //         "classroom_id": 1,
            //         "start": "2022-09-08 15:00:00",
            //         "end": "2022-09-08 15:55:00",
            //         "subject": {
            //             "id": 3,
            //             "name": "Engels"
            //         },
            //         "teacher": {
            //             "id": 1,
            //             "abbreviation": "TEA"
            //         },
            //         "classroom": {
            //             "id": 1,
            //             "name": "S101"
            //         }
            //     },
            //     {
            //         "id": 3,
            //         "subject_id": 2,
            //         "teacher_id": 1,
            //         "classroom_id": 1,
            //         "start": "2022-09-08 09:00:00",
            //         "end": "2022-09-08 09:55:00",
            //         "subject": {
            //             "id": 2,
            //             "name": "Nederlands"
            //         },
            //         "teacher": {
            //             "id": 1,
            //             "abbreviation": "TEA"
            //         },
            //         "classroom": {
            //             "id": 1,
            //             "name": "S101"
            //         }
            //     },
            // ])
        },
```

The problem is that every time the events are retrieved from the database the console gives the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a
> reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus
> recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component
> template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

[image]

When I build the code for production (*npm run build*), and I view the page, the page freezes completely. I also found on the internet that it may have to do with an infinity loop. But couldn't find a solution to the problem.

Does anyone know where the problem comes from?

Comment: Not familiar with this library but just taking a look at the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue#props-and-emitted-events) the `events` option is supposed to be an array of simple objects.  If you have some initial event data you need to fetch, do so in component's created or mounted lifecycle hook, set the fetched data (an array of event dates) as a `data` property, and assign that property to calendarOptions.events.  assigning a function running some asynchronous operation with other mysterious callback functions is most likely breaking the calendar component and causing your error

Comment: @yoduh the calendar can also be configured to run a callback dynamically to fetch events, or get them from a JSON feed via an AJAX request. So the OP's approach using a callback is ok in theory. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . Not being a vuejs user I can't be sure where the recursion problem has occurred though.